# How do I move apps to a SD card on Android 4.3?

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, internal-sd

On Ice Cream Sandwich, I used to use an app called [DS Super App2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidsail.dsapp2sd) but it doesn't work on Android 4.3 Jelly Bean. I'm using Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 running on Cyanogenmod 10.2 nightly (Android 4.3.1)

I already tried the `adb shell pm set-install-location` to SD card location. It made everything worst by thinking my empty 32GB micro SD was full. So I set it back to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am on android 4.2.2 so things should not be changed much on your environment. However, what I do, From **Settings>application/apps** I get my all applications installed on my device. So, if any application supports to be moved on to SD card, i can simply move it by pressing the **Application icon>move to sdcard**.

If it doesn't help. Try using [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD). This should do your job.

Comment: There's no Option like that to move apps to SD on 4.3. DS super Apps to sd used to rely on your method but it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you could partition your SD on a PC with one for the user area and the other for apps, copy /data partition to the app section on the sd  then edit the mount points by finding out the partition id of the app section on your sd then mounting /data on it.